# problems connectiong to phpmyadmin in linux

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I can connect to mysql terminal! no problem there; however, when I try to connect to phpmyadmin using same username/password. I get "Access Denied" and another error: "Cannot load mcrypt extension. "Please check your PHP configuration"
I have tried to setup phpmyadmin by conging to the setup page and entering the config data, but still can't login.

thanks

Comment: How did you install PHP? Using your distribution's package manager?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is whether the PHP mycrypt extension is installed.

```
if(function_exists("mcrypt_encrypt")) {
    echo "PHP mcrypt is installed/loaded, so your error is different.";
} else {
    echo "mcrypt is not installed or loaded!";
}
```

I would bet it isn't. The username/password probably moves through there at some point, so the top-level error is that your username/password do not match but the actual issue is with mcrypt.

Comment: can I put the above code inside a php page in the webroot or can I also execute it in terminal

Comment: I put it in a php file at the webroot, and it is telling me is not installed.. how can I installed?

Comment: Open a support ticket with your hosting provider and inquire how to go about getting mcrypt will be the fastest way. They likely have a process or some documentation.

Comment: I'm dong this on virtual machine (virtualbox) I have full control of the machine...